# Trigger for insert on identity column

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table A with an Identity Column which is the primary key.
The primary key is at the same time a foreign key that points towards another table B.

I am trying to build an insert trigger that inserts into Table B the identity column that is about to be created in table A and another custom value for example '1'.

I tried using @@Identity but I keep getting a foreign key conflict. Thanks for your help.

```
create TRIGGER dbo.tr ON dbo.TableA FOR INSERT
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON
begin
    insert into TableB
    select @@identity, 1;
end
```

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` is not valid here. Try `INSERT TableB SELECT identity_column_name, 1 FROM inserted;`

Comment: I tried that as well but there is a foreign key issue. It seems that the identity column is calculated only after the insert, and I need it before to avoid the error...

Comment: Are you sure you're chasing a foreign key to the right table? This should be no different than `BEGIN TRAN; INSERT tableA; INSERT TableB SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); COMMIT TRAN;`

Comment: Table A identity column is a primary, and at the same time a foreign key that points towards Table B.
Therefore INSERT tableB should take place before the Insert in TableA to avoid the constraint issue.

Comment: Then you need an INSTEAD OF trigger, not an AFTER trigger.

Comment: When I use an Instead Of I cannot insert in TableB because the Identity has not been created yet

Comment: You have lost me with chicken and egg syndrome. Are there foreign keys pointing in *both* directions?

Comment: I found the solution: `select max(identitycol) + IDENT_INCR('TableA') from TableA`

Answer (score 0):

alexolb answered the question himself in the comments above.  Another alternative is to use the `IDENT_CURRENT` function instead of selecting from the table.  The drawback of this approach is that it always starts your number one higher than the seed, but that is easily remedied by setting the seed one unit lower.  I think it feels better to use a function than a subquery.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [tbl_TiggeredTable](
    [id] [int] identity(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [other] [varchar](max)
)

CREATE TRIGGER [trgMyTrigger] 
    ON  [tbl_TriggeredTable] 
    INSTEAD OF INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE

    SET identity_insert tbl_TriggeredTable ON
    INSERT INTO tbl_TriggeredTable (
        [id],
        [other]
    ) 
    SELECT
        -- The identity column will have a zero in the insert table when
        -- it has not been populated yet, so we need to figure it out manually
        case i.[id]
        when 0 then IDENT_CURRENT('tbl_TriggeredTable') + IDENT_INCR('tbl_TriggeredTable') 
        ELSE i.[id]
        END,
        i.[other],
    FROM inserted i
    SET identity_insert tbl_TriggeredTable OFF

END
```